# How Can I Install TypeScript with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, installation, typescript

This is a popular question that I will provide the answer for.

Comment: Is there any difference when installing this for Windows 7?

Comment: Just an update to my above comment: this works fine for me in Windows 7, too. Perhaps this question should be altered to remove the reference to "Windows Vista".

Comment: I was not aware that the standard installer does not work on Windows 7.  Is that the case?  If so I will update the title.

Comment: Sorry; I think my comment was ambiguous. What I meant was the problem and your solution seem identical in Windows 7. So I'm suggesting that maybe the "Windows Vista" references in the question be removed so Windows 7 & 8 users can also know that this applies to them.

Comment: (Regarding the standard installer, it works fine in Windows 7, but it doesn't add TypeScript support to Visual Studio 2010; I think this is the same situation as with Vista & 8.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## TypeScript Version 0.9.1.1

Typescript 0.9.5+ have a dependency on Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0.dll.  Therefore, these instructions will no longer be updated.

The following is provided for educational purposes.  Please adhere to all licensing and redistribution requirements.  For prior versions of TypeScript, please see the edit history for this answer.

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Intall the [Wix Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/)
3. Download [TypeScript for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790) version 0.9.1.1 and place the installer executable in its own temporary directory.
4. Open a command window in the temporary directory.
5. Execute the command `"%wix%\bin\dark.exe" -x .\TypeScriptSetup TypeScriptSetup.0.9.1.1.exe`
6. Go to the directory .\TypeScriptSetup\AttachedContainer\packages\TypeScript_CORE
7. Execute the following commands

   ```
   IF NOT DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) SET ProgramFiles(x86)=%ProgramFiles%
   SET VSDir=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
   SET Devenv=%VSDir%\devenv.exe
   ```

### For Windows 7 Users

Execute the command:

`TypeScript_CORE.msi /l* log.txt VS11_EXTENSIONS_DIR="%VSDir%\Extensions\Microsoft" VS11_NEWSCRIPTITEMS_DIR="%VSDir%\NewFileItems" VS11DEVENV="%Devenv%" VS11_TARGETSINSTALLFOLDER="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TypeScript"`

### For Windows Vista Users

You will need to build a new installer using Wix

1. Execute the command `"%wix%\bin\dark.exe" -x .\TypeScript_CORE TypeScript_Core.msi`
2. Optionally copy TypeScript_CORE.wxs to TypeScript_CORE.wxs.bak (advisable)
3. Edit TypeScript_CORE.wxs replacing the lines shown below.  To avoid possible copyright issues and due to size limitations on StackOverflow, the entire updated file has not been posted.  The best I can do is post a diff report.  Numbers in the first column are line numbers for the original file.  Numbers in the second column are the line numbers in the edited file.  The line numbers in the edited file will be lower due to deleted lines.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
3           <Product Id="{5A908D89-0620-4CC0-A8B8-2CB4A7B0772C}" Codepage="1252" Language="1033" Manufacturer="Microsoft Corporation" Name="TypeScript for Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012" UpgradeCode="{F15B62A0-4478-4924-876A-867617EC4B8C}" Version="0.9.1.1">
4               <Package Comments="This installer database contains the logic and data required to install TypeScript for Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012." Compressed="yes" Description="TypeScript for Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012" InstallerVersion="500" Languages="1033" Manufacturer="Microsoft Corporation" Platform="x86" />
    3       <Product Id="{5A908D89-0620-4CC0-A8B8-2CB4A7B0772C}" Codepage="1252" Language="1033" Manufacturer="Microsoft Corporation" Name="TypeScript for Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010" UpgradeCode="{F15B62A0-4478-4924-876A-867617EC4B8C}" Version="0.9.1.1">
    4           <Package Comments="This installer database contains the logic and data required to install TypeScript for Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010." Compressed="yes" Description="TypeScript for Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010" InstallerVersion="405" Languages="1033" Manufacturer="Microsoft Corporation" Platform="x86" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
15(delete)              <CustomAction Id="VS11_CAUpdateConfig" Property="VS11DEVENV" ExeCommand="/updateConfiguration" Return="ignore" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />
16(delete)              <CustomAction Id="VWD11_CAUpdateConfig" Property="VWD11EXPRESS" ExeCommand="/updateConfiguration" Return="ignore" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
222                                 <Directory Id="MSBuild_Microsoft_VisualStudio_11" Name="v11.0">
    220                             <Directory Id="MSBuild_Microsoft_VisualStudio_11" Name="v10.0">
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
293             <Feature Id="TypeScriptInstallation" Level="1" Title="TypeScript for Microsoft&® Visual Studio® 2012 Setup">
    291         <Feature Id="TypeScriptInstallation" Level="1" Title="TypeScript for Microsoft&® Visual Studio® 2010 Setup">
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
427(delete)             <Property Id="WixPdbPath" Value="D:\nightly\release-0.9.1.1\srcSetup\wix\outs\x86ret\enu\cooked\TypeScript_CORE_net.wixpdb" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
663                 <ProgressText Action="CAIsVSRunning">Checking if Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012 is running</ProgressText>
    660             <ProgressText Action="CAIsVSRunning">Checking if Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010 is running</ProgressText>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
712                     <Control Id="VSRunningStatus" Type="Text" X="25" Y="110" Width="320" Height="110" Text="Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012 is running, It is recommended that you close it before proceeding [ProductName] Setup." TabSkip="yes" />
    709                 <Control Id="VSRunningStatus" Type="Text" X="25" Y="110" Width="320" Height="110" Text="Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010 is running, It is recommended that you close it before proceeding [ProductName] Setup." TabSkip="yes" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
739(delete)                     <Control Id="LaunchScreenAgreeLine" Type="Hyperlink" X="25" Y="138" Width="320" Height="14" Text="You must agree to the <a href="[EulaURLName]">License Terms</a> before you can install TypeScript" TabSkip="yes">
740(delete)                         <Condition Action="hide">Installed</Condition>
741(delete)                     </Control>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
799                 <Custom Action="WindowsFolder_x86_VC.F9D0B380_EB85_31D4_96AC_C6CB40086A55" Sequence="1" />
    793             <Custom Action="WindowsFolder_x86_VC.F9D0B380_EB85_31D4_96AC_C6CB40086A55" Sequence="2" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
803(delete)                 <Custom Action="VS11_CAUpdateConfig" Sequence="6598">VS11DEVENV</Custom>
804(delete)                 <Custom Action="VWD11_CAUpdateConfig" Sequence="6599">VWD11EXPRESS</Custom>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
830                 <InstallFinalize Sequence="6600" />
    822             <InstallFinalize Sequence="6500" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
834                 <Custom Action="SystemFolder_x86_VC.F9D0B380_EB85_31D4_96AC_C6CB40086A55" Sequence="1" />
    826             <Custom Action="SystemFolder_x86_VC.F9D0B380_EB85_31D4_96AC_C6CB40086A55" Sequence="2" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
860                 <Custom Action="SystemFolder_x86_VC.F9D0B380_EB85_31D4_96AC_C6CB40086A55" Sequence="3" />
    852             <Custom Action="SystemFolder_x86_VC.F9D0B380_EB85_31D4_96AC_C6CB40086A55" Sequence="4" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
874                 <Custom Action="WindowsFolder_x86_VC.F9D0B380_EB85_31D4_96AC_C6CB40086A55" Sequence="3" />
    866             <Custom Action="WindowsFolder_x86_VC.F9D0B380_EB85_31D4_96AC_C6CB40086A55" Sequence="4" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
889                 <Custom Action="WindowsFolder_x86_VC.F9D0B380_EB85_31D4_96AC_C6CB40086A55" Sequence="3" />
    881             <Custom Action="WindowsFolder_x86_VC.F9D0B380_EB85_31D4_96AC_C6CB40086A55" Sequence="4" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

4. Execute the command `"%wix%\bin\candle.exe" TypeScript_CORE.wxs`
5. Execute the command `"%wix%\bin\light.exe" -o TypescriptVista TypeScript_CORE.wixobj`
6. Execute the command `TypeScriptVista.msi /l* log.txt VS11_EXTENSIONS_DIR="%VSDir%\Extensions\Microsoft" VS11_NEWSCRIPTITEMS_DIR="%VSDir%\NewFileItems" VS11DEVENV="%Devenv%"`

### Config File

Existing projects will need to have the following elements added to the bottom of the project file.  Note the elements that have been added prior to the BeforeBuild element.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES3</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptIncludeComments>true</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES3</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptIncludeComments>false</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
     Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">  
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>-->
```

### Misc

Uninstalling may need to be done twice before TypeScript no longer appears in the *Programs and Features* list.  After uninstalling the first time, refresh the application list by hitting F5. Some files may still be present after uninstallation.

There are additional custom properties for debugger paths in the TypeScript_CORE.msi.  I am assuming at this point that VS 2010 is not compatible with script debugging back to a different source file.   However, someone else may wish to try to get this working.  The other custom property names are: VS11_DEBUGGER_DIR, VS11_DEBUGGER_X64_DIR, and VS11_REMOTEDEBUGGER_DIR

There are additional custom properties to enable install with one or both of visual web developer or visual web developer express.  I do not have the ability to test an install with these products.  The custom properties in the TypeScript_CORE.msi file related to this install are: VWD11_EXTENSIONS_DIR, VWDExpress11, and VWD11_NEWSCRIPTITEMS_DIR

### Functionality

- The new project type and item type are available.
- TextEditor\TypeScript section under the Tools\Options menu.
- Intellisense editing of .ts files.
- .js files are built on build or on save (when build on save has been set in the text editor options).
- The .js file appears as a child of the .ts file in the solution explorer but is saved in the same path as the .ts file. (v 0.9.1.1 does not include the .js file in the project by default)
- .ts files are not included when publishing, just the .js files.
- .ts files have their own icon and are associated with visual studio.

### Revision History

- Update for TypeScript version 0.9.1.1
- Updated for TypeScript version 0.8.3.1
- Fixed missing instruction to
  copy MSBUILD directory for 0.8.3

### Screenshots

[image: Project Template Screenshot]
[image: Editor Screenshot]
[image: Solution Explorer Screenshot]
[image: TypeScript Options Screenshot]
[image: FileIcon Screenshot]

Comment: File "TypeScriptLS.vsix_FILE " is not in extracted content for TypeScriptSetup.0.8.3 :(

Comment: You must use the 0.8.2 versioned MSI which has the .VSIX VS Extension  installer. Microsoft removed the .VSIX in TypeScript 0.8.3 onwards.

Comment: Thank you @Geotarget for the information.  I have updated the instructions based on your comment.

Comment: Oh and unpacking with 7zip gave me 100 garbage files. I had to use the MSI extracter app to do it right. You may want to add that in too. https://code.google.com/p/lessmsi/

Comment: The solution has been updated for 0.8.3.1 using lessmsi unpacking as mentioned by @Geotarget.  This is arguably a "cleaner" install than the instructions that were provided for the 0.8.2 release.

Comment: What about installing the VSIX file? Doesn't that step have to come anywhere?

Comment: There is a vsix manifest file included in the extension folder.  The old vsix installer just uncompressed and copied the extensions folder path.  VS iterates through the extensions folder hierarchy and loads the extensions automatically.  No installation is required.  I verified this using devenv.exe /log

Comment: I followed the instructions. Creating new project failed (missing build targets). I solved it by copying SourceDir\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TypeScript to C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0

Comment: @Eiver Thank you.  I had a feeling when I left on Friday that I was missing something in the instructions.

Comment: Tried with 0.9 - ActivityLog.xml unhappy with .NET Framework 4.0 unavailable.  I'll try it again later after work, but I'm suspecting the latest version 0.9 will require .NET Framework 4.0's mscorlib

Comment: The installation instructions remain the same for version 0.9.0. Do not rename existing folders.  I did run into an issue that seemed to resolve after I ran devenv.exe /log   More on the issue here. https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1189?FocusElement=CommentTextBox

Comment: I've noticed this answer doesn't make use of the `Debugger` directories from the installer. Should they also be put somewhere?

Comment: The errors work fine for me; they are specific, they include the file name, and they block the build. Note that I did *install* TypeScript before following your directions; I don't know if that's related.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work when debugging against Internet Explorer. I tried copying the *Debugger* directories' contents to `Common7\Packages\Debugger` and `Common7\Packages\Debugger\X64`, but it didn't seem to help. I wasn't sure where to put the remote debugger.

Comment: Note that TypeScript has been updated to 0.9.0.1. The Visual C++ redistributable has been updated to Update 3. I've confirmed that your instructions still work. Can you please update the link descriptions? I tried to, but my edit was rejected.

Comment: As of 0.9.1 the installer now seems to be an EXE that Lessmsi won't install, someone else ran into the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186506/how-to-use-lessmsi-to-install-typescript-for-vs-2010 and I was wondering if anyone had an idea?

Comment: @RichardCollette Thanks so much for the update; just to clarify, do we need to execute `1."%wix%\bin\candle.exe" TypeScript_CORE.wxs` to 3, if running on a Windows 7 machine?

Comment: @Richard You should not need to run candle on a Windows 7 machine.  Windows 7 has Windows Installer 5.0 installed which is the requirement for the MSI file.  On Windows Vista, the install must be repackaged as a Windows Installer 4.5 msi.  That said, I have not actually tried the Windows 7 install (I would have to set up a VM).  If it is working with VS 2010 on Vista though, I have to believe the  installer would work on Windows 7.

Comment: got this error when creating a new project http://j.mp/16NVqFX fixed it by copying the TypeScript folder from the folder v11.0 to v10.0

Comment: @RăzvanPanda - Is your operating system Vista or Windows 7?

Comment: @RichardCollette: Windows 7 Home Premium

Comment: On 32-bit Windows, the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` environment variable doesn't exist, so users on this platform should instead use `%ProgramFiles%`.

Comment: In Windows 7, I received the following error: `Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : updateConfiguration.

Use:
devenv  [solutionfile | projectfile | anyfile.ext]  [switches]`.

Comment: Regarding my above comment, I think running `devenv /Setup` will achieve the equivalent functionality,  although it's slower.

Comment: @Sam - In Vista, removing the call to devenv.exe /updateConfiguration during the install didn't seem to have any impact on functionality.  If the install is failing on Windows 7, you might want to try creating the Vista custom installer and seeing if that works cleaner.   IF the install completes, I wouldn't worry about the updateConfiguration portion failing, unless you find something is not working.

Comment: I've improved your Windows 7 installation instructions in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19900852/238753). Feel free to incorporate some or all of it into yours.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for the current version of TypeScript, 0.9.5 for me. It installed fine, but the editor was no longer available; Visual Studio opened "ts" files in the plain text editor. Make sure not to try to install it unless you're willing to troubleshoot this

Comment: It also installed its build targets under ` C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0`, but correcting this didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Lastly, the unmodified setup says it needs Internet Explorer 10. However, installing IE10 also didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I also noticed that the double uninstall problem affects Windows 7, too.

Comment: The above problem about the MSBuild targets not being in the `v10.0` folder actually affects your above instructions for 0.9.1.1 as well. I hadn't realised this earlier since I had installed a previous version of TypeScript prior to installing 0.9.1.1. I've updated my answer to define the `VS11_TARGETSINSTALLFOLDER` variable to fix this. (This is all Windows 7-specific.) I might see if I can edit yours to fix it, too.

Comment: I've also noticed that uninstalling using *Programs and Features* leaves behind a lot of files in Program Files. Uninstalling by running the installer using your command seems to help, but even it still leaves behind the extension directories under the VS directory. The left over files can be quickly found and removed by using a tool like [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) to search for them.

Comment: Is it possible to view, or be alerted to, compile errors when using Typescript in VS2010 ?

Comment: Build errors should appear in the build output window when you build the project.  I don't recall if they appear in the error window.  I have since moved on to VS 2012.

Comment: Do I still have to go through all those trouble for v1.0 in VS 2013?

Answer (score 3):

After following [Richard Collette's Windows 7 instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14510512/238753), the installer should produce the following error and then complete:

> Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : updateConfiguration. Use: devenv [solutionfile | projectfile | anyfile.ext] [switches]

If this causes any problems, running the following command may help

```
"%Devenv%" /Setup
```

Comment: Appreciate you sharing.  Since I am unable to test this in 32bit Windows 7 without the effort of setting up a VM, this is probably best left here under your name separately.  You also deserve any upvotes related to this specific part of the instructions.