# How to get TypeScript working with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2013

I have downloaded Typescript plugin for Visual Studio, installed it and restarted my PC. I have also installed both VS 2013 Express for Web and VS 2013 Ultimate Preview but TypeScript is just not there. There are no File Templates, No Project Templates, nothing.

What are the various ways you have got TypeScript to install properly/show up in Visual Studio? I have tried many different things like looking for the `vsix` file and opening it (but that file does not exist in this version of TypeScript - unless they've moved it somewhere else), I've tried downloading and installing Web Essentials - but their website says that they no longer support TypeScript because apparently VS supports it natively now. I've also uninstalling/reinstalling TypeScript - many times.

I've even tried downloading the old version of TypeScript 0.8.3 but every single link I've found just redirects me to the new download page for 0.9.1.

Nothing works.

How do I get TypeScript working with *either* VS 2013 Express for Web *or* VS 2013 Ultimate Preview?

I've seen forum posts and comments all over the web where people say that it's working for them. I have no idea what'd going on.

Comment: Same issue here... upvoted the question, and hope there is a real resolution.  In the meantime, i am going to downgrade to VS 2012 to see if i can install it there.

Comment: New package with visual studio 2013 support available:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/10/17/typescript-and-the-road-to-1-0.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a question on here with an answer that almost worked. But after changing some things around I was able to get this working. These steps slightly deviate from the original, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510511/how-can-i-install-typescript-with-visual-studio-2010).

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Install [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) x86 version (even if running on an x64 platform; tsc.exe is an x86 application).
3. Download TypeScript for Visual Studio 2012 version 0.9.0.1
4. Uncompress/Extract the `MSI` file to a temporary location using https://code.google.com/p/lessmsi/
5. Copy the directory `SourceDir\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`
   to `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs`
6. Copy the directory `SourceDir\VS11_EXTENSIONS_DIR\TypeScript`
   to `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft`
7. Copy the the two files in the `SourceDir\VS11` folder (`file.ts`, `newtypescriptfileitems.vsdir`)
   to `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\NewFileItems`
8. Copy the folder `SourceDir\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript` to
   `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0`
9. Modify your path environment variable to include `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`
10. Start visual studio.

These exact steps led to me being able to work with full TypeScript support in Visual Studio 2013 Preview and Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web. A big thanks goes to the dude who posted this answer.

Comment: Problem.  TypeScript 2012 0.9.0.1 lead me to a download page from MS listing 'TypeScript for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013'... looking through the detail tab shows that this is version 0.9.1.1, and this is an .exe, not an .msi.  As far as I can tell, all the download links that used to lead to the .msi for 0.9.0.1 are now forwarded to this new link.

Comment: @Steve, the download on the TypeScript website leads to a download for version 0.9.1.1 which see,s to be a new version. Maybe this version will install in VS 2013?

Comment: @user2645707 Nope... it was a fail.  It is an .exe, so you can't even pull tsc.exe out of it, and once it is installed under VS2013, I wasn't able to see and TypeScript options anywhere; that was why I was here.

Comment: Personally, I have given up on Visual Studio... it is a great solution if you are working on a MS IIS server, but those are too few and far between for the mess involved.  Have moved over to PhPStorm, easy TypeScript compilation, as well as Compass... it's really what I needed in the first place.

Comment: The install instructions for TypeScript on VS 2010 have been updated for version 0.9.1.1   It appears that the installer is designed to handle VS 2012/2013 out of the box.  Inside the installer package it is called TypeScript_MSI.msi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510511/how-can-i-install-typescript-with-visual-studio-2010/14510512#14510512

Comment: nasty stuff, all those steps, what is MS playing at

Comment: @FutuToad I think subconsciously they're trying to drive business away lol :P

Comment: @user-12506 yeah, I'm happy with web storm, its a much better for TS!

Comment: what if you are not using VS?

Answer (score 6):

I searched for the version from step 3 of Spike's answer, which is apparently only any executable now.  That lead me to MS's download of a slightly newer version at:

[TypeScript Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790)

Once that was downloaded, I ran it and it offered to Repair or Uninstall TypeScript for VS 2012 and VS 2013.  (I already had VS 2013 and 2013 Web Essentials installed but a project that uses TypeScript wouldn't load for me.)

Once the Repair was completed, then the project with TypeScript loaded just fine.  So it might be worth it to just try repairing the install of TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

I installed RC 3 on Visual Studio 2013 and everything was fixed.

[Visual Studio RC3 Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43398)

Answer (score 0):

According to the description [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fa041d2d-5d77-494b-b0ba-8b4550792b4d) you cannot have the standalone version and the update containing the component at the same time.

I have VS2012 and VS2013 on my system and had a lot of issues with the typescript support (or lack of) with VS2013.

So I uninstalled the typescript 1.0.0 tools for Visual Studio 2012 and re-applied Visual Studio 2013 Update 3. 
It is now working fine but some details, the project migration were not done properly, I had to exclude the ts and js files, re-include the ts file and make sure that the build action is "TypeScript compile".