# Is it possible to have TypeScript support in Visual Studio Express for Windows?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, typescript, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-extensions

I got my hands on Windows 8 machine and, willing to check out new Windows Runtime API, downloaded VS 2013 Express for Windows. WinRT offers possibility to code in HTML5/CSS/JS, but I'm interested in using TypeScript as an alternative to JavaScript when not coding for DOM. This possibility is outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201754.aspx), but only applicable to Visual Studio 2012 and not even to Express edition, as Web Essentials extension won't work there.

TypeScript web page [claims](http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download) that full support is built into VS 2013 Update 2 RC. However, while this update does install some new extensions and TypeScript gets installed in Program Files as well, it doesn't add TypeScript support to VS 2013 Express for Windows. I still don't get to create .ts file, let alone have it compiled from IDE.

Please note this is a different question from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086074/how-to-get-typescript-working-with-visual-studio-2013), which deals with VS 2013 **for Web**. I've checked the accepted answer there and it won't work. I'm interested in getting TypeScript to work with either VS 2012 Express for Windows 8 or VS 2013 Express for Windows. I'll also accept an answer pointing me to alternative IDEs for WinRT/Store Apps development, but web research tells me it's unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly possible to write a Windows Store app using TypeScript in the Express for Windows version of Visual Studio 2013. But unfortunately it isn't supported right out of the box. You'll have to modify the project file yourself.

This sounds harder than it is... I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.timmykokke.com/2014/04/enabling-typescript-compilation-in-windows-store-apps/) on how to this some time ago. It basically comes down to adding some xml to the project file, telling Visual Studio what to do with the .ts files.

After modifying the project the .ts files are compiled and even placing breakpoints inside the .ts files works.