# how to use lessmsi to install TypeScript for VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, typescript, command-prompt

I am trying to use [lessmsi](https://code.google.com/p/lessmsi/) to Uncompress/Extract an msi file to a temporary location  , which is number (4) on the list of things to do while [installing TypeScript with VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510511/how-can-i-install-typescript-with-visual-studio-2010)

I tried performing an extraction as admin via the following command prompt in the directory where the msi file exists, using:

```
C:\Users\John\Downloads>lessmsi x TypeScriptSetup.0.9.1.exe C:\Users\John\Downloads\newWork
```

but it is telling me:

> 'lessmsi' is not recognized as an internal or external command
>   operable program or batch file

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Also I can right click and extract using WE, but I only have the zip. option I see no sign of the GUI that lessmsi talks about

Answer (score 0):

Install instructions for TypeScript 0.9.1.1 have been updated at [How Can I Install TypeScript with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510511/how-can-i-install-typescript-with-visual-studio-2010/14510512#14510512)

Comment: The 0.9.1 installer is an `EXE` though; it appears they've changed it from an `MSI`?

Comment: Ah yes.  Sorry, I was confusing this with version 0.9.0.1 - They are also now sending telemetry data as part of the install.  You can see it if you enable fiddler when you launch the installer.  The installer reads through WAY too much of the registry as well if you look in procmon.   This is going to be much more difficult to resolve.

Comment: @John My answer has been updated to point back to the original install instruction which have been updated for TypeScript 0.9.1.1