# Typescript 0.9.1.1 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, windows-installer, typescript

I am currently trying to integrate typescript into vs 2010 by [following these instructions for windows 7 described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14510512/2663472).

Please do not mark this as duplicate because I am having a problem with the provided solution to my question and cannot comment on the solution.

> I followed your instructions closely but sadly it's not working for me. During installation of typescript I get an warning from VisualStudio concerning `devenv.exe: Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : updateConfiguration.`
>
> After clicking okay the installer reports that the installation was successful. when I start VS without creating or opening a project, after a while I am greeted with another error:
>
> [image]
>
> Confirming, that I do not want to get bugged about this again i create a new typescript(!) project, which gets denied with a more severe notification:
>
> [image]
>
> I checked all the folder paths I added as parameters to the .msi file and it looks like everything is in place. Any ideas how to resolve this?
>
> Thanks!

Comment: Instead of posting links to images, it would be more beneficial if you included the error dialogs as text in the question. Makes it searchable, and thus easier to find for other people with the same problem.

Comment: next time, i will do so. I was quite in a hurry and copying from those boxes was not possible so i quickly took some shots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose there is a missing folder  redirection in the answer you referenced, the VSTools msbuild folder is not being redirected.

If you open up the `%programfiles%\msbuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Typescript` folder, is the target file present there? Try copying the whole folder to `%programfiles%\msbuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Typescript`.

On a more serious note, Typescript is usually used for Web Development, Web development  project types are almost 100% backwards compatible between  VS2012, VS2013 and VS2010,  so why not upgrade to make use of these features.

It can hardly be a support issue, since backhacking Typescript into VS2010 is  surely putting you in the unsupported bucket.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Copying the folder allowed me to create a new Typescript project with everything in place. Syntax Highlighting and Intellisense wont work but i assume thats what i get for being in the "unsupported bucket"
The only thing that keeps popping up is the error about "VSTS for Database Professionals".

My company licensed vs2010 only so i need to stick to it.

Comment: The VSTS Database Professionals thing should not be related to TypeScript... But you can try reinstalling/repairing it to be sure.