# Is it possible to use angular 2 in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, angular

I am new to Angular, just wanted to know that is there any way to integrate my Visual Studio 2010 project with angular 2 ? As i am unable to get nuget package of angular 2 under my visual studio 2010.

Thanks,
-Jack

Comment: You have to use `npm` to get all `angular` packages... you can't get the angular 2 packages in `nuget`, I'm not sure about Typescript will work with vs2010 or not, but do check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14510512/2435473) for manual configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think VS2010 has project support to Angular 2 however you could use VS2015 instead.

There is always the free Community version if licencing is an issue. You could download it here https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads

To setup Angular2 in VS2015 check out this blog, its got some great setup instructions.
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio

You could also use Visual Studio Code for your Angular project. https://code.visualstudio.com/ 
You would have to use node to get the packages.

Comment: Great, it seems to be the way its going now days. Good luck with your project.