# TypeScript with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, typescript

Is there are any way to work with `TypeScript` on `Visual Studio 2010` ?

here what im tired :

> I have read the some `articles` and `stackoverflow articles` those are created base on `2012` and not those ways are not working

any new way to fix this ?

Comment: Is VSCode not an option? https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Install TypeScript with Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510511/how-can-i-install-typescript-with-visual-studio-2010)